# Rewriting a specific getJSON() line that uses API to work in JS

Tags: javascript, jquery

for reasons that don't need exploring at this juncture, I'm trying to rework a short JS file that uses plenty jQuery stuff into a pure JS file. I'm very new to JavaScript so it's slow going, but most of it is easy enough, except for one line that is well beyond my knowledge.

This is the half-edited code in question:

```
function $(x) {
  return document.getElementById(x);
} 

function formFunction() {
  var issn = $("issn").value;
    $.getJSON('https://doaj.org/api/v1/search/journals/issn%3A' + issn, function(data) {
        if(data.total === 0) {
```

On hitting Submit on the website, the user submits an ISSN (like ISBN, but for journals) in the format XXXX-XXXX (this pattern is set in the html). The submitted value is assigned to the variable issn, at which point I need to test whether the journal represented by the given ISSN is part of the DOAJ - the Directory of Open Access Journals. If it isn't (data.total === 0), one thing happens, else, blabla, etc, this is the easy part. In the past, this was clearly done with the getJSON function, but that's not an option for me and I don't know enough about jQuery or APIs to figure this out for myself.

Any help would be very much appreciated!

PS: I believe the DOAJ is up to version 2 now, if that matters in this instant.

Comment: Use Fetch, it has built-in support for converting JSON responses.

Comment: See the examples here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch